# Helm 2to3 migration, do I run helm delete after successful migration?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have successfully migrated from helm version 2 to 3 using the `helm 2to3` plugin based from the blog here: https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/

I see both releases/apps when running `helm list` and `helm3 list`. Do I need to run the `helm delete <release_name>` to verify that the app is running under version 3?

Updated: 7/29

I deleted using `helm delete <release_name>` and the helm2 release/app got deleted. In helm2, I list the apps, the status says "deleted" but in helm3 it says "deployed". It also deleted the pods. I thought it will only delete the release under helm2 and should not affect the pods. In this case helm3 status is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run the `helm delete` command. Still use the `2to3` [plugin](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/) using the command:

```
$ helm3 2to3 cleanup --name <release_name>
```

(`helm` is version 2 and `helm3` is version 3)

Check the helm release with `helm list`, the app/release should be gone.
Check the helm3 release with `helm3 list`, the app/release should still be there.

Comment: Hey many thanks for the answer. I had this question, i have batch file which uses "Helm upgrade --install" command for pulling the latest images from container and deploying it in kubernetes. Post migration with helm3 when i run this command am still getting this error. "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(ServiceAccount): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceAccount" Any help, why we are seeing this exception?

Comment: Based on what the error is saying "unknown field...", validate the yaml charts using the `helm lint` command.

Comment: thanks!. Did you perform redeployment of the services post migration?